# Full character map

Tags: windows, character-encoding, special-characters, characters

The windows Character Map tool only displays the characters from code point 0x21 (U+0021) onwards. Is there a standard (or known) tool that would display all characters of a font including the range 0x00 to 0x20?

Comment: 0x20 is the space character, so you will not see anything if it is displayed; while the lower characters are control characters, such as tab, form feed, etc, so there is nothing to display in a list other than the hex code itself.

Comment: @AFH I know that the range 0x00 to 0x20 are control characters. But a font like [Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_(typeface)) displays special characters based on Code page 437. It is these characters I want compare to other fonts.

Comment: The control characters are the same in all fonts: changing font changes only printable characters, which why Character Map doesn't include them.

Comment: one thing that sprung to mind was Babelmap http://www.babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.zip  but it turns out displays them with question marks but gives a description, so that doesn't help you much though. I guess you want to compare different codepages, and you're saying different codepages have different control characters.. can you give an example of how different codepages have different control characters or display them differently?  you could try the alt.comp.freeware newsgroup too though for a newsgroup you may want a junk (or gmail?) email address lest you get spam.

Comment: @barlop Babelmap is exactly what I'm looking for. At first I thought it did not display the bitmap fonts, but then I played around with the settings and just before I started to think I had to write my own app, I found it! You can list it as an answer to this question. Thx!

Comment: @barlop just to add to your question about the "codepages have different control characters". No, that is not what I said or suggested. All fonts map characters to Unicode code points/pages, it is just that not all fonts have typefaces for control characters in the ranged U+0000 to U+001F

Comment: @FrancoisNel I at this stage haven't managed to find which fonts have glyphs for control characters or get babelmap to display it, but since you figured out how, I suggest you post an answer with images, that'd be very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been suggested to me that there is a tool called [BabelMap](http://babelstone.co.uk/Software/BabelMap.html)

This tool seems to give exactly what I wanted. 
Just note that if you want to to view Raster Fonts (or bitmap fonts) like the Terminal font, you will first need to do the following:

1. Click on **Fonts | Single Font**
2. Then click (select) **Fonts | List Bitmap Fonts**